# OAuth2 without confirmation code using Python requests

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, python-requests

I am trying to get a response from [payever's API](https://api.payever.de/?shell#authentication)

I managed to get the authorization token using only my client_id and my client_secret, the problem is when I try to pass in the paramters as suggested by the documentation, I get the following error response:

```
u'{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"OAuth2 authentication required"}'
```

I assume it is because I didn't go through the whole OAuth2 flow, the problem is that to be compliant with that, I would need a confirmation code, which I never need since I can obtain the access token using only my client_id and client_secret.

Any ideas on how to do this? I have looked all around, trying to skip even some steps with the requests_oauthlib:

```
import requests_oauthlib

token = get_token(client_id, client_secret)
oauth = requests_oauthlib.OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_uri, scope=scope)
oauth.token = access_token
oauth.access_token = True

payments_url = 'https://mein.payever.de/api/payment'

rr = oauth.get(payments_url)
```

but no luck

```
u'{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The access token provided is invalid."}'
```

EDIT:

I used subprocess.check_output('curl -......') and worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the Payever API, I would not use requests_oauthlib, but pure requests instead. API seems to be extremely simple, so there is no need for Oauthlib.

I would start by accessing the resources with directly Curl in terminal or using  pure Requests-library in Python. 
API referece shows following way to get token:

```
curl -k https://mein.payever.de/oauth/v2/token \
-d client_id="{client_id}" \
-d client_secret="{client_secret}" \ 
-d grant_type="http://www.payever.de/api/payment" \ 
-d scope="API_CREATE_PAYMENT"
```

JSON response contains access_token and it can be used to access the resource with Curl command explained in the reference: [Payever API reference](https://api.payever.de/?shell#create-payment)

Comment: Thanks for your time lipponen, I will go then for the curl commands using os.system since my script is all in python.

Comment: I just used Curl as an example. Requests-library is maybe the easiest choice for you, you don't need to use system calls. Check the documents from http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: I used requests to get the access token and os.system to get the final response